# Botão Next e Prev do datapicker não aparece

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

A imagens dos botões direito e esquerdo não aparecem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

arquivos css que instanciei:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.theme.css"/>
```

js:

`<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

```
$("#data-checkin").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
                dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
                monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    return [date.getDay() == 0, ""]
                }
            });
```

e coloquei a pasta images na pasta img dentro da pasta webroot.

Comment: Talvez seja útil mencionar qual linguagem/plataforma/framework estás utilizando para fazer esse datepicker.

Comment: Opa, estou utilizando framework cakephp.

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: E quanto ao código que você inicia o `datepicker`?

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente, você mudou a hierarquia de pastas do jQuery UI.

A pasta `images` do jQuery UI tem de estar dentro da sua pasta `/css/`, pois os caminhos para as imagens no css são relativos, exemplo:

```
.ui-icon,
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
  background-image: url("images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png");
}
```

Comment: burrice da minha parte, nem vi o caminho.. Valeu

Comment: Acontece, principalmente por parte do jQuery de não deixar explícito que a hierarquia de pastas deve ser mantida.